# Vector spaces and field extensions, and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: vector-spaces, extension-field

Let $k$ be a field, and $\widehat{k}$ a field extension of $k$. Then $\widehat{k}$ can be interpreted as a vector space over $k$.

Is some converse also true ?

That is: given $k$, is there a criterion for a vector space $V$ over $k$ so that $V$ arises from a field extension as above ?

I am not restricting to finite-dimensional spaces (so the Axiom of Choice might come into play).

Comment: To say the least, $V$ needs to be a division algebra

Comment: The [tag:axiom-of-choice] tag is for questions about its actual necessity in proofs. Since we know of vector spaces which are not fields, even in ZFC, this is not really relevant here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: see my comment on Pete L. Clark's answer below.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not entirely sure what's the question here. Yes, a field extension has "more scalars" than the field, so if a vector space is a field extension, it has non-scalar automorphisms. Ergo, not every "infinitely generated" vector space can be a field extension. But I'm not sure what your choice-related question is in this case.

Answer (score 8):

You are asking if every vector space $V$ over $k$ can be endowed with the structure of a field extension of $k$.  The only invariant of a vector space is its **dimension**, so the question can be rephrased as:

> As we range over all field extensions $l/k$, which cardinal numbers $[l:k] = \operatorname{dim}_k(l)$ arise?

As often happens for this type of cardinality question, it is actually the finite case that is the interesting one.  If $[l:k]$ is finite, then $l/k$ is algebraic.  If we suppose that $k$ is perfect (e.g. when $k$ has characteristic zero) then by the Primitive Element Theorem we then have $l = k[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in l$, so that there is some monic irreducible polynomial $P \in k[t]$ such that $l \cong k[t]/(P)$.  In other words, over a perfect field the question of which finite numbers arise as field extensions is equivalent to the question of what are the degrees of monic irreducible polynomials over $k$.  It is well known that the answer depends on $k$.  For instance, if $k = \mathbb{C}$ or is algebraically closed then the only possible degree is $1$, and if $k = \mathbb{R}$ (or is real-closed) then the only possible degrees are $1$ and $2$.  On the other hand, if $k$ is a finite field or $k = \mathbb{Q}$, for instance, then all finite degrees occur.

In contrast, I claim that for any field $k$ and any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, there is a field extension $l/k$ with $\operatorname{dim}_k l = \kappa$.  Indeed, let $\{t_i\}_{i \in \kappa}$ be a set of indeterminates indexed by $\kappa$ and take $l = k(t_i)$ to be the corresponding rational function field (the fraction field of the ring of polynomials in these indeterminates).

Comment: I guess you use some form of choice in this construction ? I know that without choice, there are vector spaces without nontrivial (= scalar) automorphisms, and if vector spaces come from field extensions, they do have nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: So upon accepting the Axiom of Choice (so that every vector space has a basis and a well-defined dimension), infinite-dimensional vector spaces come from field extensions.

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong--the degree of $k(t_i)$ will be $\max(\kappa,|k|)$, and so there may not be extensions of infinite degree less than $|k|$.  For instance, $\mathbb{C}$ has no field extensions of countably infinite degree.